# JavaScript: 2 questions on JSON data manipulation

Tags: javascript, json

I have two arrays of objects:

```
data = [
        {"value": 10.2, "cat": "A", "state": "MA"},
        {"value": 5.3, "cat": "B", "state": "MA"},
        {"value": 20.1, "cat": "A", "state": "NY"},
        {"value": 17.3, "cat": "B", "state": "NY"},
        {"value": 7.7, "cat": "A", "state": "CT"},
        {"value": 11.3, "cat": "B", "state": "CT"}
       ];

reference = [
             {"state": "MA", "increment": 4.1},
             {"state": "NY", "increment": 0.3},
             {"state": "CT", "increment": 20.6}
            ];
```

**Questions**

1. How can I pull all `state` fields from `reference` without a loop? Specifically, a function like this `reference.pullElement("state")` returns something like `["MA", "NY", "CT"]`. Does this exist? Do I have to create a `reference` object and build the following logic into a method?

   `var states = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < reference.length; i++) {
       states.push(reference[i]["state"]);
   }`
2. How can I add  the `increment` field from `reference` to `value` field in `data`, so that I can have a new array like this.

   `output = [
              {"value": 14.3, "cat": "A", "state": "MA"},
              {"value": 9.4, "cat": "B", "state": "MA"},
              {"value": 20.4, "cat": "A", "state": "NY"},
              {"value": 17.6, "cat": "B", "state": "NY"},
              {"value": 28.3, "cat": "A", "state": "CT"},
              {"value": 31.9, "cat": "B", "state": "CT"}
             ];`

I am trying to do the following for Question 2, but the actual data has a lot more categories than this. Is this the most efficient way to do it?

```
var output = data.slice();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < reference.length; j++) {
        if (data[i]["state"] == reference[j]["state"]) {
            output[i]["value"] = data[i]["value"] + reference[j]["increment"];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you against using a library like underscore to do it, or do you need a solution from scratch?

Comment: Q1: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Note that internally, of course, you can't avoid looping through the collection.

Comment: Q2: Transform `reference` into an object using `state` as the key and `increment` as it's value. Now you can look up increments using the state key and avoid nested loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to use the (relatively new) methods that are now available on arrays, you can do the following.

1.

```
// Produce an array of state strings
var states = reference.map(function(el) { return el.state; });
```

2.

```
// Produce an object with state strings as keys and increments as the values
var stateIncMap = reference.reduce(function(items, item) {
    items[item.state] = item.increment;
    return items;
}, {});

// Here's an alternate version of the above, using forEach() instead of reduce():
// var stateIncMap = {};
// reference.forEach(function(el) {
//     stateIncMap[el.state] = el.increment;
// });

// Update elements' values using the increments
data.forEach(function(el) {
    el.value += stateIncMap[el.state];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vY5Sr/